# Can't change default login shell on OSX Monterey

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, shell

I prefer to use bash on my Mac, but the version provided by Apple (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)) cannot glob files with accented characters, so using homebrew, I have installed a later version, 5.1.16, in /usr/local/bin/bash. But I can't seem to use it at all. I have tried the following ways to use it:

1. Using chsh:
   **/Users/sjc:** `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`
   Changing shell for sjc.
   Password for sjc:
   chsh: no changes made.
   **/Users/sjc:** `bash --version`
   GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21).
   **/Users/sjc:** `which bash`
   `/bin/bash`
2. Using chpass:
   **/Users/sjc:** `sudo chpass -s /usr/local/bin/bash sjc`
   Changing shell for sjc.
   chpass: no changes made
   ****/Users/sjc:**** `bash --version`
   GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21).
   **/Users/sjc:** `which bash`
   `/bin/bash`
3. In Terminal --> Preferences --> Command (complete path) I have entered `/usr/local/bin/bash`. But when Terminal opens a new window, '`>bash --version`' and '`>which bash`' show that version 3.2.57 is running. Interestingly, if I use iTerm and set the default login to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, the prompt is '`$bash-5.1`', but '`bash --version`' and '`which bash`' show that version 3.2.57 is running.
4. In Preferences --> Users and Groups, I have gone into 'Advanced Options' to reset my login shell to `/usr/local/bin/bash` and re-started my machine. But I still get version 3.2.57.

`/private/etc/shells` and `/etc/shells` both list `/usr/local/bin/bash` as an 'acceptable shell'

Any ideas?

Comment: Both `bash --version` and `which bash` only show you that /bin is earlier in your PATH than /usr/local/bin. They don't tell you anything about your login shell

Comment: My apologies, it turns out that I am running the new shell after all. 

bash-5.1$ echo $BASH_VERSION. 

5.1.16(1)-release. 

The problem is with the new shell. I was testing it by asking it to glob files of the form 'Früh*', and it reported 'No matching files'. However, it was happy to glob files containing 'ä' and 'ö'! A little searching reveals that this is a known problem on Macs and is due to the way that they represent strings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219482/bash-ps-grep-for-process-with-umlaut-os-x for the gory details. The workarounds are explained on this page.

Comment: Thanks, had this same problem and it was just the order of the $PATH not looking for the homebrew version first